# How to enumerate all available WiFi networks using Delphi

Tags: delphi, networking

How can I detect all WiFi networks availables using Delphi?

[image]
<sub>(source: [filebuzz.com](http://www.filebuzz.com/software_screenshot/full/36690-lucidlink_wifi_client.jpg))</sub>

Comment: Do you have anything that you've tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i found this link

[I want to work with Wifi with Delphi. How?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1527418/i-want-to-work-with-wifi-with-delphi-how)

Answer (score 3):

There's a [Native Wifi API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms706556%28VS.85%29.aspx) from Microsoft which should allow you to do things like that. Unfortunately, of course - it's C/C++ only :-(

If you feel like you can convert that to Delphi yourself, go for it! Otherwise, you might have to check and see if anyone (possibly [JEDI VCL](http://jvcl.delphi-jedi.org/)?) has already done a Delphi translation of that API, or is thinking about doing it.

Marc